# How to verify the signing certificate on an APK matches the SHA256 fingerprint?

Tags: android, certificate, apk, sha256, fingerprinting

[image]

Refer to the screenshot, please.

If I have gotten the APK file, how to verify the signing certificate on the APK matches the mentioned SHA256 fingerprint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apk files are just zip files which you can unzip them. after unzipping the apk, find the `CERT.RSA` file in `META-INF` folder and run this command

```
keytool -printcert -file C:\Path\To\CERT.RSA
```

in its output you can find the SHA256 fingerprint

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tried the solution. It worked for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can verify the signing certificate directly from APK file below is the shell command:

```
$ keytool -printcert -jarfile file.apk
```